# How to run a website on c# with double click over a launcher/.exe/etc?

Tags: c#

What im intending to do is to run a website application as if it were a desktop application, double click and it would open in internet explorer.

The point is I want to make a website to create read and archive data me and my team create on our IT company on a daily basis from a single point.

This is because eventually the website would go online, but for the time being I need feedback from **no programmers** in my company working on other locations than the offices I currently am working on so they cant try it on my computer.

I just need them to be able to double click on something and run the website, try it and else on their local computers.

Opening the source code on visual studio and then compiling it is already too hard for these people (managers) thats the whole reason of this.

Im programming on c# using visual studio profesional

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you just create this website and let it run on a machine in the office? If I'm understanding your correctly. It is difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: I'd say you're better off either actually hosting the website somewhere (even if it's just off of your personal laptop, or some dev machine in your office) or converting the app to be an actual console/windows application instead of a website.

Answer (score 1):

Make a shortcut. I don't know the browser you are targeting, but here's a link for IE

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168124

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on which platform your website is built upon.
Assuming you're using `ASP.NET`. You will find that the file "making the server go live" is some executable in the `IIS` folder (Assuming your friends have `IIS` installed...). Using a batch file, you can make it automatically start the server according to your files and launch the browser.
That is if I understood you correctly. Anyway, this isn't a very good thing to do...